# Is it possible to share image in Shared Image Gallery accross tenant and subscription?

Tags: image, azure

I have `Azure AD 1` and `Subcription 1` where shared image gallery is being hosted. I also have `Azure AD 2` and `Subscription 2` where I'd like to create VM from shared image gallery version. I gave `user 1` in `Azure AD 2` reader permission to Shared Image gallery which works fine and that `user 1` can see all images in shared image gallery. Question is how do I create VM from image since the only option `user 1` sees in subscription is `Subscription 1` since it's logged to `Azure AD 1`. How do I deploy that image to `Subscription 2`?

Comment: Did you check this already ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/shared-image-galleries#access

Comment: Yes, RBAC works fine. I can see images with user from Azure AD 2. Question is how do I deploy those images to subscription which is under Azure AD 2 since in portal it only shows Subscription 1 as destination option